# Find the coordinate of users given a specific range

Tags: python, geolocation, geopy

I have a list of users' latitude and longitude.
The input will be the user's lat/lon and a range. ex. 500 meters 
I want to find out which users are in the range of 500 meters from that list.

using geopy.distance I can find the distance between two points..

```
newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796, 100)
cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391, 100)
print(distance.distance(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).km)
```

What I want is to find the points giving distance.

Something like this-

```
coor  = [(35.441339, -88.092403)
        ,(35.453793, -88.061769),
        (35.559426, -88.014642),
        (35.654535, -88.060918),
        (35.812953, -88.120935)]


def findClosest(coor,userCoor,ranges):
    pass


userCoor = [35.829042, -88.039396]
ranges = 500 #meter or km

findClosest(coor,userCoor,ranges)

## Output:The coordinates of the user are within 500 meters
```

Comment: there's only a 1000x diff between a meter and a kilometer...

Answer (score 0):

For example, if the number of users is not very large, you can sort users by distances and return the closest users according to `ranges`. The function would begin like this:

```
def findClosest(coor, userCoor, ranges):
    dist = []
    for i, u in enumerate(userCoor):
       dist.append((distance.distance(coor, u).km, i))
    dist = sorted(dist)
    ...
```

Otherwise, if a faster solution is needed preprocessing users might be necessary, for example, computing a voronoi diagram of their locations or something similar.